# Why does my if statement command not been functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to program an ATM machine with this code in python. But regardles of what is inputted, it just says that the card is successfully inputed.

```
inputCard = input("Welcome to the atm machine, please insert your credit card (Type 'Yes' when you have done so) ") 

if inputCard == ['No', 'no']: #checks if card has been entered
    print ("Please retry")  

else:
   print ("Card is successfully inputed") `
```

Thanks

Comment: should be `if inputCard in ['No', 'no']:` (`inputCard` is not a list). or maybe `if inputCard.lower() == 'no'`.

Comment: You can also write `if inputCard == 'No' or inputCard == 'no':` to check for both cases

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works

Answer (score 2):

The equality operator `==` compares whether the input, which is a string,  equals the right hand side, which is a list. Intuitively, a list will never equal a string.

So, use the `in` operator to see if the answer is in the possible options:

```
if inputCard in ('No', 'no'):
```

Alternatively, convert the answer to lowercase and then use `==`:

```
if inputCard.lower() == 'no'
```

This way will accept `no`, `No`, `NO` and `nO`.

Comment: This will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the "inputCard" to a list. Try:

```
if inputCard.lower() == "no":
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputCard` is str,`["NO","no"]` is list.They will not equal.And you can try like this

```
if inputCard.lower() == 'no':
```

or

```
if inputCard.upper() == 'NO':
```